# no viable overloaded '=' for std::find when using vectors of pairs

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to convert an iterator into an int. The iterator is given by using std::find however I am getting the error: no viable overloaded '='. I am thinking the issue may be because the two vectors I am using are vectors of pairs but I am really not sure. I got this error also:

```
candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from '__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int> *, vector<std::pair<int, int>, allocator<std::pair<int, int>>>>' to
      'const __normal_iterator<int *, vector<int, allocator<int>>>' for 1st argument
    class __normal_iterator
```

Here is that segment of my code:

```
 std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> nodat;
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> unknown;
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> measure;
  for(int i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++){
    if(std::find(iso.begin(), iso.end(), vec[i]) == iso.end()){
      nodat.push_back(vec[i]);
    }
    else{
      vector<int>::iterator it;
      it = std::find(iso.begin(), iso.end(), vec[i]);
      int index = std::distance(iso.begin(), it);
      if(HalfLife[index] == 1e-50){
        unknown.push_back(vec[i]);
      }
      else if(HalfLife[index] > 1e-8){
        measure.push_back(vec[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you get an error - include the complete error message, not just your rephrasing

Comment: Try to use `auto` where possible, it helps to prevent you from typing the specific type, especially if you can type it wrong.  `auto it = std::distance(iso.begin(), it);`

Comment: Is the error on the line using `iso`?  What's `iso`?  Can you provide a [mre] to minimize guessing?

Comment: from `nodat.push_back(vec[i])` and `std::find(iso.begin(), iso.end(), vec[i])`, I am inferring that `iso` is of type `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` since you didn't mention it. Then, change `std::vector<int>::iterator it;` to `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator it;` as `std::find(iso.begin(), iso.end(), vec[i])` returns an iterator for `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`. Or as AlexeyLarionov mentioned, use `auto`. You can remove the declaration of `it` and write `auto it = std::find(iso.begin(), iso.end(), vec[i]);` and `auto index = std::distance(iso::bein(), it);`

Comment: I'm almost inclined to close this as a typo.  Did you really mean `vector<int>::iterator it;` and/or just lost track of the iterator type being returned by `std::find`?  Usage of `auto` would have prevented this.

Comment: Using auto seemed to work well thanks for the help @AlexeyLarionov